# gRPC Does not run after the docker container is built

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, grpc, grpc-python

I have a container with the following image:

```
FROM python:3.6.2

COPY ./services/api/requirements.txt /myapp
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . /myapp/src
WORKDIR /myapp/src/services/api

COPY ./.env /myapp

CMD python server/grpc_main.py & python main.py
```

and here's a my grpc_main.py file (Mirza is the name of the server :)) ):

```
ef serve(mirza_server):
"""serve builds server

:param mirza_server: an instance of mirza server
:type mirza_server: MirzaServer
"""

server = grpc.server(futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=200))
mirza_server_pb2_grpc.add_MirzaServicer_to_server(mirza_server, server)
server.add_insecure_port('0.0.0.0:50051')
server.start()
server.wait_for_termination()


@click.command()
@click.option('--env', default='.env')
def main(env='.env', boxes_path=None, genres_path=None, editorials=None):
    mod_path = Path(__file__).parent
if boxes_path is None:
    boxes_path = mod_path / '../boxes.json'
if genres_path is None:
    genres_path = mod_path / '../genres.json'
if editorials is None:
    editorials = mod_path / '../editorials.json'

binding_spec = MirzaBindingSpec(env, boxes_path, genres_path, editorials)
obj_g = pinject.new_object_graph(binding_specs=[binding_spec],
                                 modules=[mirza, shared_utils])
server = obj_g.provide(MirzaServer)

serve(server)
```

The code is absolutely fine in grpc_main.py file and it should be run when the container is built due to this command `CMD python server/grpc_main.py & python main.py`. BUT it doesn't! when I run it manually it runs without any problems. So I don't have any clue why this happens
Do you know why?

Comment: IIUC `gprc_main.py` is the server and I assume `main.py` is your client. You should probably not run both processes in a single container. Instead you should create one container image for your server and another container image for your client. It is generally best practice to run a single process in a single container. Docker provides some guidance on running [multiple services in a container](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/multi-service_container/) .